# Adding Bootstrap Less to Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Modular Sinatra app and I'm trying to add the Bootstrap less to the application.

```
get '/bootstrap/application.css' do
  less :"bootstrap/bootstrap"
end
```

I have all less files in views/bootstrap, including bootstrap.less.

I get this error:

```
 Less::ParseError at /bootstrap/application.css 'reset.less' wasn't found.
```

The first real line of Bootstrap.less is:

```
 // CSS Reset
 @import "reset.less";
```

I've tried all different path formats, but it never finds the files it's looking to import. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried passing the `:paths` config option?

```
get '/bootstrap/application.css' do
  less :"bootstrap/bootstrap", :paths => ["views/bootstrap"]
end
```

I've had problems with this option in the past but it may work for you.

Comment: I actually just found the source in Sass and used it because it seemed be a little easier to setup. I think i'd probably compile for production anyway, so this was just for ease of development. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that worked for me here: [Parsing LESS options in a Sinatra app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606703/parsing-less-options-in-a-sinatra-app)

Since this question was the one I found first on Google, I thought I'd leave the link here so that others can find it.