# Less hangs Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, less

I am trying to add Bootstrap to a Sinatra application. I have setup routes to compile `bootstrap.less` and `responsive.less`. Loading the two stylesheets separately in a web browser works as expected. But when I try to use them in a html page my application hangs. I can only stop the application with `kill -9`.

It seems that somehow Less imports and multiple stylesheets cause a hang of the application. I was able to isolate the problem:

**app.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'sinatra'
require 'less'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

get '/style1.css' do
  less :style1, :paths => ['views'] 
end

get '/style2.css' do
  less :style2, :paths => ['views'] 
end
```

**views/index.haml**

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Hello World
    %link{'rel' => 'stylesheet', 'href' => 'style1.css', 'type' => 'text/css'}
    %link{'rel' => 'stylesheet', 'href' => 'style2.css', 'type' => 'text/css'}
  %body
    %h1 Hello World
    %p Hello World
```

**views/style1.less**

```
@import "mixins.less";
@import "shadows.less";

@color: #00eeff;

h1 {
  color: @color;
}
```

**views/mixins.less**

```
.box-shadow(@shadow) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
  -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
  box-shadow: @shadow;
}
```

**views/shadows.less**

```
h1 {
  .box-shadow(6px 6px 3px #888);
}
```

**views/style2.less**

```
@color: #ccff00;

p {
  color: @color;
}
```

Accessing the index page hangs Sinatra. If I comment out `style2.less` in the html page or inline `shadows.less` or `mixins.less` in `style1.less` the page loads as expected.

Any idea what could be the problem or how I can debug this further?

Comment: +1: Well asked first question.

Comment: Perhaps try `Less.paths << settings.views` seen in the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606703/parsing-less-options-in-a-sinatra-app. Directly telling the Less config object makes sense to me. Also I believe `paths: ["views"]` is redundant and only used if your imported less files were sitting somewhere other than `/views`.

Comment: `paths => ['views']` is not redunant. It needed by the Less compiler to resolve its imports. The question @danneu refers to is about a bug in the tilt gem which is already resolved in the latest version from git.

Comment: @svnieuw: Ah, thanks. It was rude of me to presume that you hadn't already tried googling it yourself. Doesn't answer your question but I have the Sass port of Bootstrap working in a Sinatra app with pretty much the same code.

Comment: As an alternative suggestion, why not precompile the assets? I have an app running Bootstrap, and (using Guard) I would precompile all the stylesheets into CSS and then upload them as static assets. It's faster, easier, and there's no need for dynamic compilation so why do it?

Comment: Dynamic compilation is convenient while debugging. As workaround I have switched to the SASS version of Bootstrap

Comment: @svnieuw but if you use a Guardfile or just `watch` from the command line then it's even _more_ convenient, as it recompiles on save not on refresh.

Comment: I recommend switching to the sass version. AFAIK the sass version is generated from the less version and so far it appears to be up to date. I went the less way myself, which involved a lot of hackery such as manually adding the asset paths to the less paths. I did that only to realize that sprockets does not detect changes in imported (using @import) files, which turned out to be very inconvenient. As another plus, with the sass version you can easily override bootstrap variables.

Answer (score 1):

I took your files and made small changes to them:

- I renamed `style2.css` to `style2.less` so i can use Less on it, and eventually download the style2.css with the correct css syntax ---It was not working with the other extension.
- And, I told Less that the path to search for directives, was the views path of Sinatra: `Less.paths << settings.views`.

So, with these changes, the Sinatra application stopped hanging.

Comment: The `*.css` file was an error in my question. I'm only using `*less` files. I have updated my question. The hang does not always occur. It seems I'm hitting some race condition in the less compiler or ruby gem. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.